# socket: listen with backlog and accept

Tags: c, linux, sockets, server, listen

`listen(sock, backlog)`:
In my opinion, the parameter `backlog` limits the number of connection. Here is my test code:

```
// server
// initialize the sockaddr of server
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
server.sin_port = htons( 8888 );
bind(...);
listen(sock, 1);
while( (client_sock = accept(...)) )
{
    // create a thread for one client
    if( pthread_create( &sniffer_thread , NULL ,  connection_handler , (void*) new_sock) < 0)
    {
        perror("could not create thread");
        return 1;
    }
}



// client
server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_port = htons( 8888 );
connect(...);
while(1)
{
    scanf("%s" , message);    
    //Send some data
    if( send(sock , message , strlen(message) , 0) < 0)
    {
        puts("Send failed");
        return 1;
    }
    //Receive a reply from the server
    if( recv(sock , server_reply , 2000 , 0) < 0)
    {
        puts("recv failed");
        break;
    }
    puts("Server reply :");
    puts(server_reply);
}
```

On my own PC, I execute the server, which is waiting for clients.
Then I execute two clients, both of them can send and receive messages.

Here is what I don't understand:
Why does my server can accept two different clients (two different sockets)?
I set the parameter of `backlog` as `1` for the `listen` of the server, why does it can still hold more than one client?

Comment: Your "opinion" is incorrect. If you want to limit the number of connections that can be established at any point, you have to do that in your code. `backlog` only handles new connection requests that haven't been fully handled yet, not established connections.

Comment: @twalberg  OK. Now I understand. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/listen.2.html)

> The backlog argument defines the maximum length to which the queue of
> pending connections for sockfd may grow.  **If a connection request
> arrives when the queue is full, the client may receive an error with
> an indication of ECONNREFUSED** or, if the underlying protocol supports
> retransmission, the request may be ignored so that a later reattempt
> at connection succeeds.

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

In your case it means that if simultaneous connections are requested one of those can receive back an error.